# Write junit test for annotation interfaces

Tags: java, junit

I want to write test coverage for the following:

```
@Documented
public @interface FrameworkEntryPoint
{
    String value() default "";
}
```

is there a way to do this? If so, how?

Comment: What is it you want to test?

Answer (score 0):

An annotation doesn't allow implementations (algorithms), so there is not much to test except that a certain field must be present. You can do this with Java Reflection.

Say setting a field (`value` in your example) goes wrong, then the error would be at the side of the developers of Java... So even if tests would fail, you can't do much about it (except submit a bug report).

Comment: is there an example do this? I did some research, didn thave any luck with java reflection unit testing examples.